# Statement about upper density of even numbers satisfying the Goldbach condition

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

For $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, let the *upper density* of $A$ be defined by $$\mu^+(A) = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}.$$
Let $$A = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: 2n \text{ is the sum of } 2 \text{ primes}\}.$$ Can it be shown that $\mu^+(A) > 0$? What about $\mu^+(A) \geq 1/2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state-of-the art is contained in [this paper of János Pintz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09084). Read the introduction, especially (1.9).

Comment: To summarize this answer: we know $\mu^+(A)=1$ and we have good estimates on the size of the complementary set.

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes, and this information is available in the corresponding Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Rigorous_results